# "Publish" updates connection string properly, but "Publish to Azure" does not?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, web-applications, web-deployment

I've noticed that when publishing my WebApp project to Azure Cloud Services (as a web role) with VS 2013, if I use just "Publish" (which just updates the website, and not the whole VM), it correctly updates the web.config file with the connection string specified in the publish profile. But when I use "Publish to Azure" to update the entire VM, it fails to update the connection string, and leaves it pointing to the incorrect storage account or DB.
Has anybody else observed this? Strangely it seems to be doing the right thing when I use Publish To Azure on my staging instance, but when updating the production instance it's definitely not doing what I expect it to.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. You ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Well I've since observed that although the connection string now seems to be getting updated, now that we've moved to packaging our software as a SharePoint provider-hosted app, the necessary ClientID and secret key fields only get updated when clicking Publish for the app then clicking "Publish web service", so I always do publish to Azure followed by a second publish of the app/web-service now.